# Filtro de gráficas con select con JS

Tags: jquery, filtro, google-chart-api

espero me puedan ayudar. Tengo una interfaz donde muestra 4 gráficas diferentes con google charts, me pidieron que filtre estás gráficas por medio de dos select, uno las va a filtrar por trimestre y el otro por el año. Estás gráficas se encuentran en otro archivo js, lo que quiero hacer es llamar a las funciones en mi nuevo archivo y así pintar la gráfica en el div que corresponde, pero no esta funcionando como debería, si veo la consola si me toma la información de los select pero a la hora de mostrar la info me dice que el div no esta definido, incluso ya imprimi por la consola si me esta tomando div y si le esta llegando, pero me da ese error.
Este es el HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <label for="">REPORTE TRIMESTAL</label>
            <div id="seleccion">
                <label for="#">Periodo</label>
                <select class="form-control btn col-3" id="trimestre">
                    <option value="0">Selecciona el trimestre</option>
                    <option value="1" class="btn">Trimestre 1</option>
                    <option value="2" class="btn">Trimestre 2</option>
                    <option value="3" class="btn">Trimestre 3</option>
                    <option value="4" class="btn">Trimestre 4</option>
                </select>
                <label for="#">Año</label>
                <select class="form-control btn col-3" id="anio">
                    <option value="0" class="btn-anio">Selecciona el año</option>
                    <option value="2022" class="btn-anio">2022</option>
                    <option value="2023" class="btn-anio">2023</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <input id="generar" class="filtrar btn btn-raised btn-danger generar" type="submit" value="Filtrar">
            </div>       
        </div>
```

Este es el SCRIPT que tengo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let trimestre = $('#trimestre').val();
        let anio = $('#anio').val();
        
    }); 
        $('.filtrar').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        
            //valores seleccionados de los elementos <select>
            let trimestreS = $('#trimestre').val();
            let anioS = $('#anio').val();
        
            console.log('Trimestre seleccionado:', trimestreS);
            console.log('Año seleccionado:', anioS);              
        
        });
        
        
    function filterData(trimestre, anio) {
        
        if(trimestre == 2 && anio == 2023){
            let divTr2 = document.getElementById('artipacT3');
            if (divTr2) {
                console.log('Contenedor obtenido:', divTr2);
                drawChartArtipacT2(divTr2);
            } else {
                console.error('El contenedor no se encontró.');
            }
        
        }
    }   
        
});
```

De antemano gracias.

Comment: por lo menos, en tu pregunta, no aparece el tal artipacT3